# Animating the list marker with the text in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, list, animation

I'm using jQuery animation to animate the HTML list element (animation is applied to the list item) . The problem is that in IE the list marker doesn't animate with the text when the list item is animating. The marker just shows right after the text completes animation. In other browsers such as FF, Chrome,..the marker animates with the text when the list item's animation is playing.

My question is: In IE, is there any way that we can make the marker animate with the text ?

Thanks,

Can

---

```
<ol start="1" style="list-style-type:decimal;"> 
  <li id="item1" class="list_item">  Item 1 </li>
  <li id="item2" class="list_item"> Item 2 </li>
  <li id="item3" class="list_item"> Item 3 </li>
</ol>

$("#item"+item_id).stop(false, true).show("drop" , {"direction": "left"}, 5000, function(){});
```

Comment: How exactly are you animating the list item? Is it a "normal" marker or an image? You'll need to show some code. A working example would be best.

Comment: Thank you, RoToRa. Below is the code sample:                     <ol start="1" style="list-style-type:decimal;">
  <li id="item1" class="list_item">   
   Item 1
  </li>
  <li  id="item2" class="list_item">
   Item 2
  </li>
  <li  id="item3" class="list_item">
   Item 3
  </li>
 </ol>                                                                $("#item"+item_id).stop(false, true).show("drop" , {"direction": "left"}, 5000, function(){});